# ASP:Menu.SelectedValue not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, selectedvalue, aspmenu

I've been trying to use ASP:Menu.SelectedValue property but it is not working so if anyone has used this before please read on. Here is the code.

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" BackColor="#B5C7DE" 
            DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" 
            ForeColor="#284E98" onmenuitemclick="Menu1_MenuItemClick1" 
            StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" Visible="False">
            <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#284E98" ForeColor="White" />
            <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
            <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" />
            <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#507CD1" />
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem Selectable="False" Text="Analysis" Value="Analysis">
                    <asp:MenuItem Selectable="False" Text="Descriptive" Value="Descriptive">
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Mean" Value="Mean"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Median" Value="Median"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Mode" Value="Mode"></asp:MenuItem>
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                </asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>
            <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#284E98" ForeColor="White" />
            <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
            <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#507CD1" />
</asp:Menu>
```

And the code behind

```
protected void Menu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
        {
            MenuItem selectedItem = Menu1.SelectedItem;
            lblUpload.Text = Menu1.SelectedItem.Text;

            if (Menu1.SelectedItem.Text == "Mean")
            {
                lblSet.Visible = true;
                DropDownList1.Visible = true;
                btnCalculate.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

I added in the Line

```
 lblUpload.Text = Menu1.SelectedItem.Text;
```

to test the output on a visible and working label but nothing is returning. Can anyone see the problem with this?
I have also tested;

```
lblUpload.Text = SelectedItem.Text/.value;
lblUpload.Text = Menu1.SelectedItem.Value;
lblUpload.Text = Menu1.SelectedItem.ValuePath;
```

None of these affect the label in anyway. Is there problems with this control in general or am I missing an obvious mistake. Appreciate any feedback thanks.

Comment: Are you  using AJAX on this page?  When everything looks right, but no updates are being rendered, AJAX is normally the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as soon as you make Menu1 visible and change onmenuitemclick="Menu1_MenuItemClick1"  to onmenuitemclick="Menu1_MenuItemClick".

I Menu1 needs to change visibility please provide the code that shows how you do it.

Edited:

Try to break down the problem into small pieces:

1. The problem might be that you have an error trying to access the selected menu item
2. You might have a problem displaying the selected item in lblUpload

The best way check is to set a breakpoint at Menu1_MenuItemClick, start debugging by hitting F5 and have a look at Menu1.SelectedItem.Text there.

Comment: This worked thank you for some reason another click event was created, Menu1_MenuItemClick and Menu1_MenuItemClick1thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
lblUpload.Text = e.Item.Text;
```

Comment: same result, really stumping me. Is it possible that my labels cannot be seen inside this method? They are modified etc within another button click event however